# Spring Integration-Stack overflow error

Tags: spring-integration

Hi this is my SI configuration:

```
<!-- Inbound/Outbound Channels employeeSearchRequest-->
    <int:channel id="accountRequest" />
    <int:channel id="accountResponse" />
    <int:channel id="catRequestChannel" />
    <int:channel id="mataccountRequest" />
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>



    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="cwebAccountManagementGateway"     
        supported-methods="GET, POST" 
        request-channel="accountRequest"
        reply-channel="accountResponse" 
        mapped-request-headers="*"      
        mapped-response-headers="*" 
        view-name="/policies" 

        path="/services/{class}/{method}"
        reply-timeout="50000"
error-channel="errorChannel">




        <int-http:header name="serviceClass" expression="#pathVariables.class"/>
        <int-http:header name="serviceMethod" expression="#pathVariables.method"/>

    </int-http:inbound-gateway>


    <int:header-value-router input-channel="accountRequest"
        header-name="state"
        default-output-channel="accountRequest" resolution-required="false">
        <int:mapping value="MAT"
            channel="mataccountRequest" />
            <int:mapping value="CAT"
            channel="catRequestChannel" />

    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:service-activator id="accountServiceActivator" 
                input-channel="mataccountRequest"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="serviceGatewayAdapter" 
                method="requestHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>

        <int:service-activator id="caRequestActivator" 
                input-channel="catRequestChannel"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="caServiceGatewayAdapter" 
                method="requestHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>

                 <int:service-activator id="errorRequestActivator" 
                input-channel="errorChannel"
                output-channel="accountResponse" 
                ref="errorGatewayAdapter" 
                method="errorHandler" 
                send-timeout="60000"/>
```

When i call this service am getting stack overflow exception.When i tried this project in tomcat i got this stak overflow exception when ever i don specify State parameter as header with either CAT or MAT.But when i deploy in Websphere server
even after passing the state pareameter am getting stack overflow exception.Please give some solution .Follwing is entire stack trace.I could not paste entire stack so am pasting part of stack trace.

```
[3/6/14 9:37:25:819 EST] 0000012f ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: Spring Integration Services. Exception thrown : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1154)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:556)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:606)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1560)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.setHeader(MessageBuilder.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.<init>(MessageBuilder.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.fromMessage(MessageBuilder.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.history.MessageHistory.write(MessageHistory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap.preSend(WireTap.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:152)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<int:header-value-router/>` couses the issue: his `default-output-channel` is the same as `input-channel`. So, if the router doesn't resolve the channel by its mapping it send the message to its `default-output-channel`, but here this channel is the channel to get the message for that router. Since `accountRequest` is `Dirrect` channel all work is done at the same Thread. And it causes the `StackOverflowError`.

Just change `default-output-channel` to any other appropriate channel

Comment: Thanks dude...thats working fine...i corrected that...but when i try from rest console to call this service with header state as "CAT" still its not getting header

Comment: Hi am paising state as CAT from mozila rest console but its not accepting header in case of websphere.but tomcat working fine....Please give solution

Comment: "its not accepting header in case of websphere". So, this question is up to IBM. I think there is should be an option on WAS to allow/disallow custom HTTP headers.

Comment: The issuse is resolved..The problem is the header name "state"..If we give it as state it not taking header value..But for other header its taking values..So ichanged the header value from state..thanks for your help..